# Prove that $\mathrm{E}(X \ln X) \ge \mathrm{E}(X) \mathrm{E}(\ln X)$

Tags: inequality, expected-value

> Prove that $\mathrm{E}(X \ln X) \ge \mathrm{E}(X) \mathrm{E}(\ln X)$.

Can I use Jensen's inequality? Should I prove that $g(x)=x\ln x$ is a convex function? I don't know how to prove it?

Comment: Are you asking to prove $E(X \ln X) \ge E(X) E(\ln X)$?

Comment: The inequality should be $ E (X \ln X ) \geq E(X) \ln ( E(X)) $. This follows from the fact that the function $ x \to x\ln x $ on $ (0, \infty )$ is convex.

Answer (score 1):

$x\,ln (x)$ is a convex function on $(0,\infty)$since its second derivative $\frac 1 x$ is positive. The inequality simply says $f(EX)\leq Ef(X)$ which is Jensen's inequality.